# React production build is returning 404 error

Tags: reactjs, npm-scripts

```
npx create-react-app app-name
cd app-name
npm start
```

works fine but

```
npm run build
cd build
serve -s build
```

return 404

It's inbuilt react code. I have not changed anything.
running in the development server but not in the production server.

Is there anything am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't think u should `cd build` , do it directory of ur project where the build is expected to be. for example, if it's in `public/build` you will do `cd public && serve -s build`.

Comment: It did work, thanks @SultanH.